# Login failed for user SA, when connecting to SQL Server Docker container, deployed in Kubernetes

Tags: sql-server, docker, kubernetes, yaml

I'm following this tutorial on Microservices
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgVjEo3OGBI

At some point, I deploy a SQL Server image in Kubernetes, using this Yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mssql-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mssql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mssql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mssql
          image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1433
          env:
          - name: MSSQL_PID
            value: "Express"
          - name: ACCEPT_EULA
            value: "Y"
          - name: SA_PASSWORD 
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mssql5 
                key: SA_PASSWORD
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/opt/mssql/data
            name: mssqldb
      volumes:
      - name: mssqldb
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mssql-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql-clusterip-srv
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: mssql
  ports:
  - name: mssql
    protocol: TCP
    port: 1433
    targetPort: 1433
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql-loadbalancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: mssql
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 1433
    targetPort: 1433
```

And the PVC.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mssql-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 200Mi
```

I then create a secret in Kubernets, holding the password for the SQL Server sa account, and this secret is then used in the Yaml file.

```
kubectl create secret generic mssql5 --from-literal=SA_PASSWORD="MyC0m9l&xPassw0rd"
```

It should then be possible to connect directly to the SQL Server container on localhost port 1433, using the sa account and the password.

However, I get the "Login failed for user SA" error when trying to connect. I've tried everything, including changing SA_PASSWORD to MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD, changing the complexity of the password, enabling login for the sa user in  SQL Server, which was disabled before and googled like I've never googled before. TCP/IP setting is enabled in SQL Server configuration manager. I cannot get access. Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: First step would be to consult the `kubectl logs` output of the pod to see if it's even starting up successfully, or if it's reporting any "18456" login errors. In the latter case look at the `State` number reported in the error message and compare it against the table displayed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to isolate the cause.

Comment: You need to be consistent, as per [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) use `SA_PASSWORD` in all places.

Comment: I've been changing from SA_PASSWORD to MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD back and forth to test, and I forgot to change it in the question. This is not the issue though. I'll change it in the question to not cause confusion. Good eye :)

Comment: _It should then be possible to connect directly to the SQL Server container on localhost port 1433_ Not necessarily. In k8s `localhost` only works for inter-container communications for containers residing on the same pod. When containers are deployed across multiple pods they need to use DNS names and/or specific IP addresses. Ref: [Pod networking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#pod-networking).

Comment: Looking at the logs, I can see this error:
Unable to open the physical file "/var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)"

Comment: I've tried your YAML without the persistentVolumeClaim and it works OK. Can I redirect you to this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63217356/sql-server-pods-with-persistentvolumeclaim

Comment: Ok, if I remove the persistentVolumeClaim, I can run the SQL Server container without errors, but I still get the login failed for SA user error.
Here's a question. If I look inside the SQL Server container with docker exec -it 'containerid' /bin/sh
I can cd into the /var/opt/mssql/data folder, where the master.mdf database is. Could it be because the SA account doesn't have permission to access this db? If so, how can I grant SA access?
Just a question, I am fairly new at this...

Comment: I can access the docker container db with
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "1StrongPwd!!"
So I'm guessing that the SA account has the permissions it needs...
In the tutorial video, he accesses the database directly in SSMS, using the SA account on localhost, the password specified in the secret, and the ports specified in the YAML file (1433), but I get the login error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR The solution to this particular problem was that https://stackoverflow.com/users/52045/soeren had an instance of SQL Server running on their computer that intercepted port 1433 requests before hitting K8s. Disabling the SQL Server instance on computer solved the problem and port 1433 traffic routed to K8s load balancer.

Original solution follows...

I have copy/pasted your YAML verbatim above into files `deployment.yaml` and `pvc.yaml` respectively and then run these commands.

```
kubectl create -f pvc.yaml
kubectl create secret generic mssql5 --from-literal=SA_PASSWORD="MyC0m9l&xPassw0rd"
kubectl create -f deployment.yaml
```

I can connect via localhost and create database.

[image]

[image]

Conclusion is that your YAML looks fine.

If I then delete/create the deployment again...

```
kubectl delete -f deployment.yaml
kubectl create-f deployment.yaml
```

..the SSMS connection still works and the Test database persists.

The only change I would personally make is from `- mountPath: /var/opt/mssql/data` to `- mountPath: /var/opt/mssql/` in `deployment.yaml` so that your entire mssql path is persisted.

As you are including the `/data` folder this means that the `logs` and `secrets` folders are still within the POD and not the persisted volume. This might explain the `ldf` log file permissions issue you mentioned above?

So, next I investigated the persisted volume `kubectl describe pv` and on my system it is showing the following:

```
Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/lib/k8s-pvs/mssql-claim/pvc-42f91115-efdb-4cea-90d8-204fd592f6b4
```

I'm guessing you are using hostPath, which will store the files on the containing node/host. I'm using Docker Kubernetes as opposed to minikube. A single node cluster.

If you shell into the node (as opposed to the POD) as root thus:

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1
```

You can `cd /var/lib/k8s-pvs/mssql-claim/pvc-42f91115-efdb-4cea-90d8-204fd592f6b4` to see the mounted volume for your persisted volume claim.

You should see something like:

```
/ # cd /var/lib/k8s-pvs/mssql-claim/pvc-42f91115-efdb-4cea-90d8-204fd592f6b4
/var/lib/k8s-pvs/mssql-claim/pvc-42f91115-efdb-4cea-90d8-204fd592f6b4 # ls -l
total 89348
-rw-r-----    1 10001    root           256 Feb 14 17:33 Entropy.bin
-rw-r-----    1 10001    root       8388608 Feb 14 17:36 Test.mdf
-rw-r-----    1 10001    root       8388608 Feb 14 17:55 Test_log.ldf
-rw-r-----    1 10001    root       4653056 Feb 14 17:54 master.mdf
-rw-r-----    1 10001    root       2097152 Feb 14 18:00 mastlog.ldf
-rw-r-----    1 10001    root       8388608 Feb 14 17:49 model.mdf
-rw-r-----    1 10001    root      14090240 Feb 14 17:49 model_msdbdata.mdf
-rw-r-----    1 10001    root        524288 Feb 14 17:49 model_msdblog.ldf
-rw-r-----    1 10001    root        524288 Feb 14 17:49 model_replicatedmaster.ldf
-rw-r-----    1 10001    root       4653056 Feb 14 17:49 model_replicatedmaster.mdf
-rw-r-----    1 10001    root       8388608 Feb 14 17:49 modellog.ldf
-rw-r-----    1 10001    root      14090240 Feb 14 17:36 msdbdata.mdf
-rw-r-----    1 10001    root        524288 Feb 14 17:49 msdblog.ldf
-rw-r-----    1 10001    root       8388608 Feb 14 17:49 tempdb.mdf
-rw-r-----    1 10001    root       8388608 Feb 14 17:55 templog.ldf
```

If you had mapped `mssql` only above you will see data, logs and secrets subdirectories.

Obviously, replace your PVC with your name.

So again, in conclusion your YAML looks fine. I therefore suspect that you have got something lingering around from previous attempts.

The only other issue that has cropped up with me is that sometimes it's better to use single quotes with PowerShell and double quotes with cmd prompt.

Have you checked your pods are running OK and that the config is being read OK? (replace pod id with yours)

```
kubectl get pods
kubectl describe pod mssql-depl-7777487cf7-w9gj5
```

Beyond that...I'm sure it's something to do with what's been left behind from previous testing that needs to be cleaned up.

Original answer below for completeness...

Have you tried clearing everything down (using a namespace makes this easier).

I have noticed that if you're using a persisted volume claim the master.mdf may hold an old password (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.syslogins) as the master.mdf isn't recreated fresh as it would be with a non persisted volume.

As an experiment, when I had everything working, I deleted the deployment but left the persisted volume claim.

I deleted the SA_PASSWORD secret and recreated it with a different password and then applied the deployment again.

I was able to connect to SQL from SSMS on 1433 using the old password even though the new POD contained the new password in the environment variable SA_PASSWORD.

In conclusion, I would try to clear your persisted volume claim and start again so that the master/msdb databases are recreated.

It's worth a try?

Incidentally, NodePort is all you need and not ClusterIP and LoadBalancer for your service (this obviously depends on your cluster environment. I presumed you're using minikube or local Docker?)

Comment: Hi Robin. As of now, I can't make it work with the PVC. If I leave it in my deployment YAML file, the deployment fails. If I comment it out, I can deploy and access the db using my command prompt with localhost and SA user. Can't access in SSMS though. I have had it up and running with the NodePort, the ClusterIP and LoadBalancer is part of the tutorial, so I'm just doing as I am told :-D

Comment: What error are you getting when using PVC? The password error? Is it possible that you have another deployment/pod running that is also sharing the same PVC and getting a locking error with master? I don't think it's a good idea to have more than one SQL Server POD/Container running pointing to the same data, logs PVC. Another observation - I wonder if mountPath: /var/opt/mssql/data would be better as mountPath: /var/opt/mssql so that the logs and secrets directories are also persisted. If you can get the actual error message when using PVC that would help to find problem.

Comment: Another observation is that you haven't provided your PVC YAML.  What is your accessModes set to? ReadWriteMany, ReadWriteOnce, etc.

Comment: I have edited the question, and added the PVC.yaml. I will do some more testing and add the error messages regarding the PVC.

Comment: That's very interesting. I think you are right about things left behind from previous testing. I have made many changes and attempts, so that would make perfect sense. I will go through the things you have suggested and get back with my results. Just one question; What would be the best way to clean up, and get rid of lingering problems? Is deleting a deployment enough?
Also, thank you for you help :)

Comment: Another thought. If your K8s deployment is definitely up and running and you've checked all pods, services, pvc and you still can't connect via SSMS...is it possible that you have got an instance of SQL Server running on your computer/PC that SSMS is trying to connect to before it hits the K8s 1433 port? You could try changing the LoadBalancer  port to 1434 (or similar) and connect using SSMS via localhost, 1434.

Comment: Ok, so I have tried a few things. I deleted everything, deployments, services and the PVC. Then re-created everything. Now I'm able to run the deployment with the PVC, and it runs without errors. So, that should be ok. I still can't connect to the db with SSMS on port 1433 (SA user error), but if I change the port to 1434 like you suggested, I get this message: 

"A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0"

Comment: Have you managed to login? I am following that tutorial and having the same issue.

Comment: I found that I am having an instance of SQL Server running on my laptop so that  might be the problem

Comment: Ah I found a way to make it work,

You have to go to the SQL Server Configuration Manager and turn off the MSQLSERVER service

Comment: Yeah, apparently that was the issue. I have an instance of SQL Server running on my machine as well. I just tried stopping the service, and now I can connect to the Docker db.  Seems that has been the issue all along. It never occurred to me that it could have this effect, but now, in hindsight, it makes some sense.

Comment: Yeah I think because port 1433 is taken by your host MSSQL then your MSSQL on docker cannot use the same port. it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
if you turn off that service then it will work

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have "localhost" in server name. Refer screenshot:
[SSMS configuration for SQL server running on Docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbffa.png)

- Check services.msc > SQLSERVER service is off.
- Check the password for 'sa' user