# Existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host - Kubernetes

Tags: .net, kubernetes, yaml

Im new into kubernetes and im following Les Jackson course about Microservices on YouTube. After i deployed the SQL server i cant connect to it using Management Studio. (Arround 5:30:00 on the course)

[image: As you can see SQL container is running]

Here is the yaml code for deployment, its pretty much the same used on the course i just added some lines because i was getting and error "crashLoopBackOff" on the container:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mssql-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mssql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mssql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mssql
          image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
          command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "--"] #added this 
          args: ["while true; do sleep 30; done;"] #two lines
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1433
          env:
            - name: MSSQL_PID
              value: "Express"
            - name: ACCEPT_EULA
              value: "Y"
            - name: SA_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mssql
                  key: SA_PASSWORD
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/opt/mssql/data
              name: mssqldb
      volumes:
        - name: mssqldb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mssql-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql-clusterip-srv
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: mssql
  ports:
    - name: mssql
      protocol: TCP
      port: 1433
      targetPort: 1433
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql-loadbalancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: mssql
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 1433
      targetPort: 1433
```

Pod description:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: The commands you added are overriding sqlserver from starting.  You should look into why it wasn't starting in the first place (probably kubectl logs).  I seem to recall sqlserver wants a minimum amount of resources in order to start.

Comment: @KennethIto if i remove those lines the container enters in CrashLoopBackOff, do you think the problem is my computer resources?

Comment: You should figure out what its erroring on.  Either quickly kubectl log the actual start up, or override the start up as you have in your opening question and kubectl exec in, and manually start sqlserver from the commandline to see the errors.

Comment: I vaguely recall that sqlserver has minimum hardware requirements and minimum password complexity requirements.  But it could be anything wrong really at this point.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-troubleshooting?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash#sql-server-container-startup-errors

Comment: The logs are blank, what does it mean?

Comment: You're kubectl logging the actual start up of sqlserver right?  Not the 'bash -c sleep' one.

Comment: Im logging the pod name for exemple mssql-depl-7cc4769948-g2pb

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Im using Kubernetes v1.22.5 in Docker desktop if that makes sense

Comment: @JoãoFernandes  The problem is identical to yours, in the same course [here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71096335/login-failed-for-user-sa-when-connecting-to-sql-server-docker-container-deploy). I repeated everything identically, everything work for me. Try the solution and let me know.

Comment: I've tried pretty much everything on that post and unfortunately didnt work, i've posted an image with the details of my pod and i think everything is ok

Comment: @Mykola you followed the tutorial and worked for you right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after several attempts to recreate your situation completely, I managed to do it. I have encountered several problems, the solution of which I will describe below. From the input parameters I have `Windows 10 pro`, installed `Docker desktop`, and `Kubernetes v1.22.5`. Also 2 files `pvc.yaml` and `deployment.yaml`.

1. We'll start by deleting all the previous Clusters and Nodes to start all over again. And at the end, reboot your system.

```
# Write neme of your config files 
kubectl delete -f pvc.yaml   
kubectl delete -f deployment.yaml
```

2. After that, launch `Docker desktop` and in the `Settings` tab, select `Kubernetes` and start it.
3. Launch a command-line terminal, navigate to the directory with your files and run the command:
   `kubectl create -f pvc.yaml`

Where the configuration will be:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mssql-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 200Mi
```

Run next command to create a secret:
`kubectl create secret generic mssql5 --from-literal=SA_PASSWORD="MyC0m9l&xPassw0rd"`
Run last command:
`kubectl create -f deployment.yaml`

With configuration:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mssql-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mssql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mssql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mssql
          image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1433
          env:
          - name: MSSQL_PID
            value: "Express"
          - name: ACCEPT_EULA
            value: "Y"
          - name: SA_PASSWORD 
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mssql5 
                key: SA_PASSWORD
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/opt/mssql/data
            name: mssqldb
      volumes:
      - name: mssqldb
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mssql-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql-clusterip-srv
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: mssql
  ports:
  - name: mssql
    protocol: TCP
    port: 1433
    targetPort: 1433
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql-loadbalancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: mssql
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 1433
    targetPort: 1433
```

4. After your cluster and services start, check them using the commands [`kubectl get pods`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#viewing-finding-resources), [`kubectl get services`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#viewing-finding-resources). If everything is ok and you see the output from the screenshot below.

[image]

5. You can proceed to checking your secret file by following the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) run command:
   `kubectl edit secrets mysecret`

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: v1
data:
  SA_PASSWORD: TXlDMG05bCZ4UGFzc3cwcmQ=  # << ERROR
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-03-23T17:31:31Z"
  name: mssql5
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "633"
  uid: 62184a05-7641-4296-944f-4e9a149e5bb5
type: Opaque
```

6. My password was different from the password I created. If you have also then edit the file and restart services.  After that you can connect to your `SQL Server`.
7. If the problem continues, you can connect with `Windows Authentication`, then click `Security` > `Logins` > `Properties` on your username right mouse button > `Properties` and change password there.

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for your work! After a delete and create everything like you describe it worked! When editing secrets file the password was diferent but it worked anyway with the password that i defined in command line.

Comment: But can you please try to explain what i was doing wrong? I really want to understand

Comment: I think that it was a syntax error because your code didn't work for me. I used code from Les Jackson course  git repo. And of course steps for doing this one by one.